# importing .csv file from google drive folder to an existing google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have been trying to import a csv file from google drive or gmail to google sheets.
The content includes 10 columns and the rows are not defined as it could be any range for rows
When I use the below codes it pastes everything in the fist column, could someone help.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("data.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's comma delimited with newlines at the end of each line.  Please show us the file contents

Comment: Try changing to tab delimited in the parse function

Comment: What you mean by `the rows are not defined`?

Comment: Just like Cooper has asked, how exactly does you `.csv` file look like? What kind of delimiter are actually using for its values?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with the appropriate file:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("ssid")
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

**Upon reviewing your data:**

You might be able to convert your data by using an ascii editor like UltraEdit.  If you replace "" with "\r\n" and then replace all spaces with commas and then delete all quotes.

The end result should like this:

```
Date,order_status,vehicle_category,vehicle_condition_type,Flag,channel,Orders,GMV,NR,DMP
2021-10-01,completed,Auto,Inspection,NULL,Others,3,24,4,24
2021-10-01,completed,Auto,Inspection,NULL,Others,Buyer,Pushed,3,16,3,15
2021-10-01,completed,Boost,Listing,NULL,Others,Buyer,Pushed,1,1,0,1
2021-10-01,completed,Boost,Listing,NULL,Others,Organic,4,45,1,0
```

and it will load the spreadsheet like this:

| A | B | C | D | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | order_status | vehicle_category | vehicle_condition_type | Flag | channel | Orders | GMV | NR | DMP |  |
| 2021-10-01 | completed | Auto | Inspection | NULL | Others | 3 | 24 | 4 | 24 |  |
| 2021-10-01 | completed | Auto | Inspection | NULL | Others | Buyer | Pushed | 3 | 16 | 3 |
| 2021-10-01 | completed | Boost | Listing | NULL | Others | Buyer | Pushed | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-10-01 | completed | Boost | Listing | NULL | Others | Organic | 4 | 45 | 1 | 0 |

I used the code in my answer to load the spreadsheet by putting it into a file.

Comment: Apparently now its not even loading the contents

Comment: Show us a portion of the contents on the file.  Paste it into your question.

Comment: I am unable to add an attachment in this thread... however the content is still in the first column which shud be in atleast 10 columns .. the content is not separated with commas, its separated with spaces so its even more difficult

Comment: how do I add it here ?

Comment: "Date order_status vehicle_category vehicle_condition_type Flag channel Orders GMV NR DMP"  
"2021-10-01 completed Auto Inspection NULL Others  3 24 4 24"  
"2021-10-01 completed Auto Inspection NULL Others Buyer Pushed 3 16 3 15"  
"2021-10-01 completed Boost Listing NULL Others Buyer Pushed 1 1 0 1"  
"2021-10-01 completed Boost Listing NULL Others Organic 4 45 1 0"

Comment: this is how its pasting on here

Comment: If it's not separated by commas then it's not csv try using `' '` for the second parameter of the parse method.  It may not work though because we won't be able to tell the difference between spacing in the content and delimiter spaces.  Without unique delimiters your wasting your time.  It's not going to work.

Comment: this acsii editor that you mentioned, do i need to do this to my source file ? my source file gets downloaded to drive via SQL